# Ansible global encrypted variable

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have just one vault file, containing a bunch of variables I want to keep secret.  Is there a way to load the file in Ansible just once, and then globally accessible to all roles and all tasks?

Basically I don't like to replicate var_files everywhere, like this:

```
- hosts: webserver
  var_files: encrypted.yml
  roles: ....

- hosts: dbserver
  var_files: encrypted.yml
  roles: ....
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [group_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data), which are variable files that load automatically according to the groups a host is a member of. All hosts are members of the `all` group, so you can put your common variables in `group_vars/all`.

The group_vars dir can be relative to (with decreasing priority): the playbook, the inventory file or in /etc/ansible.

If you want to separate encrypted and unencrypted common variables, you can use it as a directory as well:

- `group_vars/all/settings.yml` for the normal variables
- `group_vars/all/encrypted.yml` for the vaulted ones.

If you don't like my choice of filenames, choose your own, it doesn't matter, as long it's under the `all` group.

Answer (score 0):

No.  What you have in your example is two Ansible playbooks in a file and there isn't a higher level of abstraction in Ansible (higher than playbooks).

I wasn't really aware that this actually worked! But I believe it's just a general good practice to a have single playbook per file. After all when you run it, you run it with `ansible-playbook` and not `ansible-playbooks`

This not related to having two playbooks in a file but if you are concerned about security you should consider using [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html) (new in 1.5)

Comment: The example file has two *plays* in the playbook, not two playbooks in a file.  And it is perfectly reasonable to have multiple plays in a single playbook, e.g. you might have a play to set up webservers, followed by another to set up db servers (as in the example) where both sets of servers are working together to provide a particular web application.